# Is my file path too long and because of it I can't create files with a .bat?

Tags: batch-file

I'm using bat files to create some simple txt's inside of a folder hosted on a shared server of my company, sort of a template for folder rooting and example txt's inside for people to know what they should do.

Everything is working OK, except the example txt's creation. After some testing, I realized that if I have short names everything works, but when I create files with longer names they don't work.

Is there any workaround for this? My relative file path is really long but since it's a shared server I can't do anything about it :(

```
    @echo off & setlocal
cls
Color a0
ECHO .......This template is for template of XXXXXX........
ECHO ........................................................................
ECHO Input ONLY the XXX Number and the Version separated by a comma
set /p NumV="(No spaces are needed. It should look like '0000123,8.9'): "
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%a in ("%NumV%") do (
   set "Num=%%a"
   set "V=%%b"
)
mkdir "%~dp0\..\..\%Num%"
mkdir "%~dp0\..\..\%Num%\%Num% v%V%"
break>"%~dp0\..\..\%Num%\%Num% v%V%\%Num%.txt"
echo Some description of the rules to be followed. Example: an example of how it will look like>"%~dp0\..\..\%sNum%\%Num% v%V%\%Num%, v%V% Needed_for_XXX_Report.txt"
```

The `..\` are for all the rooting in my own Templates Folder :)

EDIT:
Example path (edited names of folders, but kept the same amount of characters):

> ```
> \\eu.company\123456fsroot\COUNTRY-1\Sub Systems 12\A3\A REALLY LONG FOLDER NAME THAT HAS SPACE AND_ 15\2021\05 - May 2021\1. General Templates\1. Name of template 1
> ```

Everything running on Windows 10 Enterprise - v1909 - OS Build 18363.1500.

Comment: The path above is just a relative path. You need to give the absolute path because that's where the limit applies. Without any changes [the maximum path length is 260 characters](https://superuser.com/a/1347053/241386) and if long path is enabled then the limit is 32767

Comment: It would certainly seem simpler if you were to begin your script with `PushD "%~dp0"`. Then you could use `MD "..\..\%Num%\%Num% v%V%"` and write your content using `(Echo content`, followed on the next line by `Echo more content`, followed on the next line by `Echo even more content) >"..\..\%Num%\%Num% v%V%\%Num.txt"`, and end with the line `PopD`.

Comment: @Compo indeed this works like a charm! Thanks!

PushD "%~dp0"
code
MD "..\..\%Num%\%Num% v%V%"
(Echo multiline
Echo content)>"..\..\%Num%\%Num% v%V%\%Num.txt"
PopD

Thanks!!